# How to implement a simple to do list using a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a simple to do list using this solution [Add user input into a ListView on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660741/add-user-input-into-a-listview-on-button-click), but when I implement the onCreate of the solution I get the following errors http://pastebin.com/9CBCMrjv I'm using fragments in this application and I'm wondering could this be causing the errors as maybe the constructors don't apply to fragments.

Can someone make sense of the errors or where I'm going wrong with this implementation? My understanding of the errors is that this solution can't be applied to my class as it is linked to a fragment instead of a plain activity.

This is the complete class to give you a better understanding of the problem:

```
    public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

ListView mListView;
EditText mValue;
Button mAdd;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
    return rootView;    
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_top_rated);

    mAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newList);
    mAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    mValue = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.listData);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

    // set the lv variable to your list in the xml
    mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);  
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String input = mValue.getText().toString();
    if(input.length() > 0)
    {
        // add string to the adapter, not the listview
        adapter.add(input);
        // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
    }
}   

 }
```

The errors

```
The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type TopRatedFragment

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type TopRatedFragment

The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (TopRatedFragment)

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type TopRatedFragment

The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(TopRatedFragment, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type TopRatedFragment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.fragment_top_rated);`

wrong

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
     mAdd = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.newList);
     mAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
     mValue = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listData);
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

// set the lv variable to your list in the xml
     mListView=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);  
     mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;    
}
```

You need to inflate a view in onCreateView and return the view

Also you use the inflated view object to initialize your views

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(TopRatedFragment, int, ArrayList<String>) is undefined
```

So change to

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);
```

get rid of the codes in `onCreate`

Comment: @BrianJ the suggestion is right. also make sure youhave the right imports. that is what i have not mentioned. Rest all should be fine

Comment: Yes that worked,might add some more features now like if I select a line item I can delete it or enter a quantity..